# Access Permission not working

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have been trying to put permission on my pdf.
    I have a method which will set the Access Permission on an instance variable called access

```
 private AccessPermission access = new AccessPermission();
    public void setPdfPermissions(boolean allowPrint, boolean degradePrint,
                boolean editPage, boolean allowAssembly, boolean allowCopy,
                boolean allowReaders, boolean editAnnotation, boolean allowFillIn) {
            if (allowPrint) { // allow printing
                access.setCanPrint(allowPrint);
            }
            if (degradePrint) { // degrade printing
                access.setCanPrintDegraded(allowAssembly);
            }
            if (editPage) { // edit page contents
                access.setCanModify(editPage);
            }
            if (allowAssembly) { // insert, remote or rotate page
                access.setCanAssembleDocument(allowAssembly);
            }
            if (allowCopy) { // copy page contents or graphics
                access.setCanExtractForAccessibility(allowCopy);
            }
            if (allowReaders) { // screen readers can copy contents or graphics
                access.setReadOnly();
            }
            if (editAnnotation) { // edit annotations
                access.setCanModifyAnnotations(editAnnotation);
            }
            if (allowFillIn) { // fill form fields
                access.setCanFillInForm(allowFillIn);
            }

        }
```

and then I m saving the access in security handler

```
StandardSecurityHandler secHandler = new StandardSecurityHandler();
             if((userPass != null) || (ownerPass != null)) {
                 System.out.println("userPass:"+userPass+"owner pass:"+userPass);
                // TODO
                StandardProtectionPolicy policy = new StandardProtectionPolicy(ownerPass.toString(), userPass.toString(),
                      access);
                secHandler = new StandardSecurityHandler(policy);
  document.setSecHandler(secHandler);
```

When Im passing false for values like setPrint as false, Its allowing me to print. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your second code block is wrong. The correct way (at least for the 1.8 versions) to encrypt a file is described [here](http://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/encryption.html). So for you, the correct code would be:

```
// owner password to open the file with all permissions
// user password to open the file but with restricted permissions, can be empty 
StandardProtectionPolicy spp = new StandardProtectionPolicy(ownerPass, userPass, access);
spp.setEncryptionKeyLength(128);
doc.protect(spp);
```

edit: see also the answer by mkl why your 1st code segment is wrong too :-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Tilman's answer, the first code block also is wrong:

For each `boolean` parameter, `setPdfPermissions` only does something if the value is `true`, e.g.:

```
if (allowPrint) { // allow printing
    access.setCanPrint(allowPrint);
}
```

This would work if *the permission by default was not granted*. Looking at the definition of the `AccessPermission` default constructor, though, one sees that the contrary is the case, e.g. in the code from 1.8.10:

```
/**
 * Create a new access permission object.
 * By default, all permissions are granted.
 */
public AccessPermission()
{
    bytes = DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS;
}
```

Thus, `setPdfPermissions` essentialis is a big NOP (no-operation) block of code.